# SharePoint client Javascript call to node.js rest api, pass credentials

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, 2016, credentials

Trigger : javascript on a SharePoint page

- This javascript calls a REST service implemented in node.js running on a separate windows 2016 server
- This REST Service executes some actions in SharePoint using the SharePoint REST API

The problem/requirement : The Node.js REST service should use the credentials of the user logged in in Trigger SharePoint page (which calls the node.js REST service)

The question: is it possible to pass (direct or in-direct) the user-credentials to the node.js REST service in a way this node.js REST service can, in turn, use those credentials to call the SharePoint REST API ?

backup question :) - would it be possible were the REST service implemented as an ASP.NET (core) Web API ?

thank you.